# Custom pictures for checkbox?

Tags: html, css, checkbox, custom-controls

I would like to show checkbox as toggle button. But I can't apply my custom pictures to it with CCS -- still checkbox is drawn. How to accomlish this task?

My CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox]#settingsbutton {
    border-style: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 42px;
    height: 40px;
    display: block;
}

input[type=checkbox].button-settings {
    background-image: url("images/button-settings-normal.png");
}

input[type=checkbox].button-settings:active {
    background-image: url("images/button-settings-normal.png");
}

input[type=checkbox].button-settings:hover {
    background-image: url("images/button-settings-hover.png");
}

input[type=checkbox].button-settings:active {
    background-image: url("images/button-settings-pressed.png");
}
```

My HTML:

```
 <body>

<input type="checkbox" id="settingsbutton" class="button-settings"/>

 </body>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want it's with pure `css` solution then you have to add `label` in your markup . It's a `trick` & write lke this:

```
input[type=checkbox]{
    display:none;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label{
    height: 40px;
        width: 42px;
} 
body:not(#foo) input[type=checkbox]:checked + label{
    background-image: url("images/button-settings-normal.png");
} 

body:not(#foo) input[type=checkbox] + label{
    background-position:0 -46px; /* as per your requirement*/
    height: 40px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>

<input type="checkbox" id="settingsbutton" class="button-settings"/>
<label for="settingsbutton"></label>

 </body>
```

Read these articles :

http://www.thecssninja.com/css/custom-inputs-using-css

http://www.wufoo.com/2011/06/13/custom-radio-buttons-and-checkboxes/

But it's not work in `IE8` & below

Comment: The links are really useful, but I don't understand why you used `display:none` on the checkbox? If it's not displayed, you can't click it? Your link suggests to set the opacity to zero instead.

Comment: You can click the label which will activate the checkbox

Answer (score 2):

See this link for styling check-boxes: http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

The solution involves hiding the check-box and adding a styled element in place of it, which emulates the check-box's behavior.

Comment: Yes saw this text, but was wondering if is it possible to use CSS only

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution if you have some text in label

```
input[type=checkbox]{
    display:none;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label:before{
    height: 42px;
    width: 42px;
    content: url("../img/chk.jpg");
} 
body input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before{
    content: url("../img/chk_checked.jpg");
}
```