# Custom designing checkbox buttons

Tags: html, css, checkbox

Im trying to custom design checkbox buttons so they don't look like the typical checkbox button. Im trying to achieve the following:

[image]

(note the **check** and **cross** marks are images.)

**Ive been able to achieve this so far:**

[image]

But I can't seems get rid of the small white checkbox where the tick appears. I am trying to change the css of the checkbox button on selection. For example is yes is checked the border turn to green otherwise stay grey.

Is possible to do?

**Edit:**

```css
.btn-primary {
  background-color: #f6f9fc;
  border: 1px solid Rgba(61, 70, 77, 0.1);
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #3d464d;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<label class="btn btn-primary">
  <input type="checkbox" value="yes">yes
</label>

<label class="btn btn-primary">
  <input type="checkbox" value="no">no
</label>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style checkbox using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css)

Comment: Yes sure they are images but can you please post your code? A fiddle would be great

Comment: @NicoO thank you for the comment. I've gone through that question, it was not able to help in my particular situation.

Comment: @JohannKratzik please see edited question.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667528/custom-pictures-for-checkbox) may help if you can use images?

Comment: Just for hiding these checkboxes:

`.btn-primary input[type="checkbox"]  { display: none;  }`

Comment: @RyanGee thank you for the link I'll try that now. But how can I remove the small white box?

Comment: clicking the label will toggle the checkbox, so you can set `input[type="checkbox"] {display: none; }` to do the trick!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just playing around, css only, no images or js:

```css
input[type="checkbox"].myClass {
  display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"].myClass + label {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px silver;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  opacity: 0.5;
  padding: 1em 1em 2em 1em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 10em;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"].myClass + label:before {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, black, black), linear-gradient(to left, black, black);
  background-size: 2px 50%, 25% 2px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0.75em 0.625em, 0.75em 0.625em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px black;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 2em;
  margin: 1em auto;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  width: 2em;
}
input[type="checkbox"].myClass + label:after {
  content: "Yes";
}
input[type="checkbox"].myClass:checked + label {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px red, 0 0 0.25em 0 silver;
  color: red;
  opacity: 1;
}
input[type="checkbox"].myClass:checked + label:before {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, red, red), linear-gradient(to left, red, red);
  background-size: 2px 50%, 50% 2px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center, center center;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px red;
}
input[type="checkbox"].myClass:checked + label:after {
  content: "No";
}
```

```html
<input class="myClass" id="o1" type="checkbox" /><label for="o1"></label>

<input class="myClass" id="o2" type="checkbox" checked/><label for="o2"></label>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is a better solution then using the images.

Comment: Just one question though, if I want to have separate boxes for "yes" and "no" how can I separate the css for both of those checkboxes? As currently the css is being applied to the global "input" element.